# How to capture HTTP traffic from a Lua process on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, lua, fiddler

I am trying to capture HTTP traffic from a process on Windows 7 by proxy configuration through Fiddler. The process is a third party executable which I found out is referencing Lua5.1.dll and is a 64 bit process. It has also been installed as a Windows Service.

The process is sending HTTP GET requests to a different process on the same machine but I cannot seem to capture those in Fiddler.

I've tried configuring a proxy through netsh.exe winhttp but this is not working either. Are HTTP requests originating from this process somehow not using WinHTTP but using something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to find out how to set proxy for Lua executable.

Have in mind, though, that even if set up the Lua executable to respect WinHTTP/WinINET proxy settings these settings are per user and the chances are your service does not run under your user account. So the first thing to try is changing the WinINET proxy for the service user account to Fiddler and restarting the service.

You can also configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy and capture the inbound traffic to that local process that gets the GET requests. That might be simpler to do. Here is a how to - http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried to configure the proxy for the sending process by setting WinHTTP/ WinINET proxies for the user account but nothing is showing up in Fiddler. I get the impression the HTTP client may be a custom implementation on top of WinSock, does that mean that I am out of luck? Would WireShark be able to capture HTTP traffic in that instance? The receiving process is a Apache2 web server on a Ubuntu guest VM. I will look into the reverse proxy configuration, I have no idea how that works and I am a bit out of my depth here :).

Comment: It is absolutely possible that the client does not care about WinINET proxy configuration. It is also possible that it cannot be configured to use proxy at all.

Comment: There is nothing complicated about the reverse proxy. Fiddler runs at the machine/port where your receiving process runs now (or at different machine/port if you can configure your client to use different request url). So Fiddler gets all the requests from the client. Fiddler then redirects these to the actual Apache2 running at another machine/port. Thus Fiddler sees the Apache2 incoming traffic.